# WHY my Python BLE device discover codes don't catch as many devices as Raspberry Pi OS panel does?

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspbian-stretch

I developed some BLE device discovery python codes from the example given in https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/blob/master/examples/ble/scan.py
which are run on a Google AIY Raspberry pi.

> from bluetooth.ble import DiscoveryService
>
> service = DiscoveryService()
>
> devices = service.discover(2)
>
> for address, name in devices.items():
>
> ```
> print("name: {}, address: {}".format(name, address))
> ```

The problem is, my python codes can only catch 2 BLE & classic Bluetooth devices nearby while the Bluetooth panel in Raspberry Pi shows 5 devices. Why is there such a big difference?

Or how can I or which library should I use for developing a BLE device discoverer which can catch as many as devices as the OS does?

Comment: `Why is there such a big difference?` ... different code works differently

Comment: How different can they be?  This sounds like a BLE discovery sensitive issue?  If this is the case, should the senitivity be a function of hardware and DSP only?

Comment: what is `2` in `service.discover(2)`?

Comment: What is the context of service.discover(2)? If it tells you that it's a man page, part 2 are system calls. For a full definition of all the man sections, do a "man man"

Comment: @Jaromanda  The '2' in ' service.discover(2) ' is an example of the discovering duration in seconds. I changed it to be 10 seconds and it didn't change the result.

Answer (score 1):

I never got PyBluez to work correctly, seeing all the devices that bluetoothctl was finding.   But PyBlue seems to work a lot better, at least on Raspberry Pi Zero W.

https://elinux.org/RPi_Bluetooth_LE